# How to create log files using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging

My project is going on using codeigniter.
I am new to codigniter and I want to bring log module into my project.
I want to capture all activities including errors into the log file.
Do i need to make changes in all page to store changes in log file.
where should i write function for this , whether in controller or library.
Is the log module feature exist in codeigniter?
can anyone give me the solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `library` or `helper` and use [Autoload](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html). AFAIK codeigniter have no such default kinda library or helper, you need create your own or do research for external one.

**EDIT :**

My bad, try to find `$config['log_threshold'] = 0;` and `$config['log_path'] = '';` in your `config.php`